# How to set Nav Bar & Toolbar Background Images in IB

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

How can I set a Navigation Controller's Navigation Bar and Toolbar backgrounds to be an image using Interface Builder?

I know how to do this in code and have done so in my app. But now I want my launch screen storyboard to reflect the app and I have to do this in IB as the app is not running at that time, so no code.

It *looks* like it cannot be done (no useful options in IB that I can see) so I am probably going to have to rethink the startup look and feel - but hoping for some solutions or workarounds I have missed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible, we can't write any custom class/code for the launchscreen xib/storyboard files, we can only design using resource files.

Maybe you can design some images that simulate your custom navigationBar/Toolbar.